# Test with JUnit using javafx linechart

Tags: java, javafx, junit, linechart

Is it possible to create tests in JUnit and initialize javafx components like linecharts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, take a look at [TestFX](https://github.com/TestFX/TestFX), it supports [JUnit 4](https://junit.org/junit4/) and [JUnit 5](https://junit.org/junit5/). Haven't seen recent active development on the project, but it works if you aren't looking for very complex tests.

Comment: For reference, see also the [tag:jfreechart] unit tests seen [here](https://github.com/jfree/jfreechart/tree/master/src).